# NodeJs Express Server to Proxy and Host Static Content

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to create a nodejs server with expressjs that serves my static react content.  How do I implement to say if you are a proxied path, proxy else return index.html.  Current code is below:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, 'build');
var proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

app.use(express.static(publicPath));

app.use('/pcs', proxy('/pcs',
    {
      target: '<target>',
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: {'^/pcs': ''},
      hostRewrite: 'localhost:3000',
      protocolRewrite: 'http'
    }));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(publicPath, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is up!');
});
```

Comment: just a side note: you are much better off doing this with a web server instead of node.js and express

Comment: @TuanAnhTran by web server do you mean something like an nginx reverse proxy?

Comment: yeah, like nginx reverse proxy

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a pattern for matching the proxy path, otherwise it will only match the exact "/pcs" path. Here is a pattern to match any route starting with "/pcs/" (in addition to just "/pcs"):

```
app.use('/pcs/?*', proxy('/pcs', 
  {
    target: '<target>',
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: {'^/pcs': ''},
    hostRewrite: 'localhost:3000',
    protocolRewrite: 'http'
  }));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, even with that change calls to /pcs/* are still returning the static content and not the expected content from the target server.

Comment: This is working correctly for me locally. What URL are you testing with, which is not being sent to the proxy?